# bootstrap : onclick navbar margin-top = 10 vh;

Tags: html, css

I would like to see the entirety of my division when I click on a link of the navbar.

```js
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbarSupportedContent' })
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body data-spy='scroll' data-target='#navbarSupportedContent'>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent"> 
    <section id="accueil">1</section> 
    <section id="recherche">2</section> 
    <section id="presentation">3</section> 
    <section id="parcours">4</section> 
    <section id="competence">5</section> 
    <section id="projet">6</section> 
    <section id="cequejaime">7</section> 
    <section id="contact">8</section>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: .]

Comment: Kindly provide the code which is causing the problem.

Comment: Kindly edit your question and add this code in the question statement.

Comment: did something have an example for offset

Comment: @WaleedIqbal i'm new sry, my problem comes from offset i think but i don't know what to show u

Comment: Ok, I edited the question to include the code, but the snippet doesn't work so it hardly helps. @Atlas, do you have any more code that could help? Please edit the question and put the code into the snippet.

Comment: @Atlas ... have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: i understand nothing sry i'm bad at English but i can give u the link of my website

Comment: http://teddyclement.com/

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are not taking into account the fact that your nav bar is absolutely positioned, and is removed from the flow of your page. Therefore, your sections are sliding in behind it and the first 10vh worth of your section is disappearing behind the nav bar.

One way to get around this is to increase the height of your sections to be 100vh and add padding to the top so that your content is pushed below your nav bar. Try this is your css instead of what you have now.

```
#presentation, #parcours, #competence, #projet, #cequejaime, #contact {
    height: 100vh;
    padding-top: 10vh;
}
```

Comment: yes I already try this and it's work perfectly (you can see it on my website now) but i really want to find an option with the property offset

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.